# Simple iOS Math

Tags: ios

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {
        int a = 1 + arc4random() % 9;
        int b = 1 + arc4random() % 9;
        self.question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d + %d", a + b];
}
```

I am trying to build a math question app and on the line with

```
self.question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d + %d", a + b];
```

it gives me an error that says

```
More '%' conversions than data arguments
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to be:

```
self.question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d + %d=%d",a, b, a + b];
```

Other option for your case is:

```
self.question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d + %d",a, b];
```

You have one argument, when you need two or three.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted! Oops! Thank you though